# JAVA crash while loading DLL library with JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

I'm migrating our project from java 6 to java 8. The application is running perfectly with java 6, but executing the same code/application on java 8 seem to be working fine untill JNA interface starts to execute. I'm getting such error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x1001354c in javaw.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
```

Google says that usually such error happens where I/O devices are involved. However, in my case just specific filter written in c++ is executed.

I suspect that the problem cause some king java security, because issue remains with java 7 where I have found that new security roles were introduced.

My attempts were to use **AccessController.doPrivileged()** method as well as give grant access for javaw.exe executable using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cacls.exe javaw.exe /f");
```

but this still does not work properly. Maybe someone has faced something familiar? Thank you!

**EDIT.** 
It looks like something might be with DLL library itself. Tried simple c++ code to use DLL library with VS2010 and the same error occurred, but with the VS2005 it runs perfectly. May be the compiler issues?

Comment: After 1.7, the JVM requires a permissions tag in each jar file's manifest.  I've only been examining this w/r/t web start failures; in what context are you running that you need `AccessController.doPrivileged()`?  Normally you only need that within an applet.

Comment: In fact, it was java applet, but now it is only Swing application. The main goal just to find out why code crash executing jna interface.

Comment: Can you make your title more specific? There are many possible problems when migrating from Java 6 to Java 8.

Comment: new title: JAVA crash while loading DLL library with JNA

Comment: What you failed to mention is: You said you are migrating from Java 6 to 8 - was your application working before (with java 6?) and starting with java 8 it stopped working?

Comment: Yes, with java 6 everything is stable and without issues. What is more interesting now, that running the code on virtual machine with java 8 I get no error as well as the code executes fine. So, I have decided to put fresh new instal on another PC, but I get the same error :-D.

Comment: Have you tried Java 7?  It might help isolate the range of possible changes.

Comment: The same with java 7... Infact tried all java 7 versions.